# click on button then automaticly send email in android

Tags: android, eclipse, email

I have an xml file which user will enter an email into it, then when click on the submit button, I want the application to automatically send an email with specific content to that email ..

any good tutorials or examples I can get help from ???

```
 package com.example.emailtest;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class main extends Activity{
public Button bsend;
public Mail m;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bsend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Mail mail = new Mail();
                try {
                    mail.send();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

logcat

```
 12-13 02:22:51.831: W/dalvikvm(2588): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail; (820)
 12-13 02:22:51.831: W/dalvikvm(2588): Link of class 'Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail;' failed
 12-13 02:22:51.831: E/dalvikvm(2588): Could not find class 'com.example.emailtest.Mail', referenced from method com.example.emailtest.MainActivity$1.onClick
 12-13 02:22:51.831: W/dalvikvm(2588): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 711 (Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail;) in Lcom/example/emailtest/MainActivity$1;
 12-13 02:22:51.841: D/dalvikvm(2588): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
 12-13 02:22:51.841: W/dalvikvm(2588): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail; (820)
 12-13 02:22:51.841: W/dalvikvm(2588): Link of class 'Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail;' failed
 12-13 02:22:51.841: D/dalvikvm(2588): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x13b3 at 0x02 in Lcom/example/emailtest/MainActivity$1;.onClick
 12-13 02:22:52.101: D/gralloc_goldfish(2588): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
 12-13 02:22:54.681: D/AndroidRuntime(2588): Shutting down VM
 12-13 02:22:54.681: W/dalvikvm(2588): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4acab90)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): Process: com.example.emailtest, PID: 2588
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.emailtest.Mail
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at com.example.emailtest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
 12-13 02:22:54.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 12-13 02:22:58.121: I/Process(2588): Sending signal. PID: 2588 SIG: 9
```

Comment: @gruszczy isn't that how the user send email from application ? I want the application automatically send email to the user

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used Java Mail API and the code below you can use. Please add the necessary details like user name,password, email ids etc  **Use this tutorial http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android**

```
    public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to ;
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = "username"; // username 
    _pass = "password"; // password 
    _from = "emailsentfrom@gmail.com"; // email sent from

    _to = new String[] {"toemail@gmail.com"}; 
    _subject = "subject"; // email subject 
    _body = "test"; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  }  
  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // adding attachment
      addAttachment("filename");//replace with file name u need

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
      transport.connect(_host, 465,_user, _pass);
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  // more of the getters and setters É.. 
}
```

and write an Async task to send mail

```
    public class SendTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

private ProgressDialog dialog;
private Context mContext;

public SendTask(Context mContext){
    this.mContext = mContext;

}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
    this.dialog.setMessage("sending");
    this.dialog.show();
}

protected Integer doInBackground(String... ids) {

    Mail mail = new Mail();
    try {
        mail.send();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for answering ! I will try it now . hopefully it will work with me :)

Comment: best of luck :). Please don't forget to add the jar files specified in that tutorial. After successful integration accept this answer :)

Comment: can you check my post please ? I did the same but it crash when I open it :( can you help me please > the mail class is like yours but I change the email,password,....

Comment: Please post your stack trace

Comment: this is the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.emailtest.MainActivity"  please make sure you added your MainActivity in manifest

Comment: sorry for bothering you x_x now I have another problem,, when I click it crash ! I posted the logcat .. sorry and thank you so much !

Comment: should I extend my mainactivity class to mail or something ? the problem is class mail is not found im I right ?

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file for your button, define `android:onClick="SendMail"`

This will call the `SendMail` function inside your activity when your button is clicked.

Next, get a reference to the `EditText` view where the user enters the email body.

**E.g.:** If the resource id of your `EditText` view is `edittext1`, then in your activity you need to do the following:

```
EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

String emailBody=ed.getText().toString();
```

Now the `emailBody` string consists of the body of the mail that the user has typed in.

Next, inside your activity, you need to define a function `SendMail()` as shown below:

```
void SendMail(String body) {
   String recipient="usrname@mail.com";
   String subject="Your subject here";
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   i.setType("message/rfc822");
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , recipient);
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);
   try {
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This approach has helped me, hope it helps you also.

Comment: where do I put the email that I will send to ? where I got from the editext ?

Comment: I think you are really new to android app development. While creating the xml file for your activity, you will drag and drop an edittext and a button. When you do so, Both these components will be allocated a resource id. So inorder to handle this in the activity, you geed to get reference to those components using their id's. Sendto address you need to put it in recepient string under SendMail() function.

Comment: no im not that new lol .. but I did not get the code .. if the recipient where I put the email that I send to , then where I put the sender email ?

Comment: @LamaTatwany: Sorry what i meant was whoever is the recepient, i.e, the person to whom you want to send a mail, his/her email id should be stored in the recepient string.

Comment: From your modified question, in your onclick method put the body of SendMail() function that i have posted.

Comment: okaaay now I got your code ! I tried it and when I click on the button it will open the email page and I enter to who I want to send the email to , and it is really great code! but what I want to do is I want when I click automatically an email will be send without the user knowing ..