# emails sent automatically from android

Tags: android, email

I'm finishing my android application and I just need to get my application automatically send, if the user wants, an e-mail containing the password for that user, I've tried the way I point out more below, but it is bad because the body of message I am sending etc appears and does not want it, I want you to be completely hidden from the user. The user enters his email and told him sent to this email with your password.
Here 's the code:

```
Intent itSend = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

//vamos a enviar texto plano a menos que el checkbox esté marcado 
itSend.setType("plain/text");

//colocamos los datos para el envío
itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ user_text});
itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Subject);
itSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, cuerpo_email+pie_email);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(itSend, "Send mail..."));
finish();
```

Comment: Make it as webservice

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/2065418

Comment: you can send using java libs as well as you need to provide a ID as well as PWd may be hidden from the sender

Comment: I have seen the answer you've given me, but I doubt it is that, it's JSSE Provider, where I put in my project? is a .java?

Comment: check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559543/click-on-button-then-automaticly-send-email-in-android/20559655#20559655